# Primus.io and passport.js

Tags: node.js, socket.io, passport.js, passport.socketio

I consider moving from [Socket.io](http://socket.io/) to [Primus.io](https://github.com/primus/primus) (due to scalability [bug](https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io/issues/952)) but one major plugin I'm missing is a primus-[passportjs](http://passportjs.org/) authorization plugin (something like [passport.socketio](https://github.com/jfromaniello/passport.socketio)).

Do you know any such plugin or code example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to "passport.socketio" team to accept a fix to make it also support Primus.io.

Comment: is there any example showing primus working with passport.socketio ?